# jar file creates auxiliary folders in random place in system

Tags: java, scala, jar

I have my **.jar** file ***MyApp.jar*** file containing the program MyApp, written in the Scala language. Inside, I use the LevelDB and Logback. When I launch my jar file ***java -jar MyApp.jar*** all the auxiliary folders, including logs and leveldb are created not inside the jar file, not near, but at an arbitrary location of the file system, is it somehow possible to fix it?

Comment: Define "arbitrary location" and share your configuration, otherwise it's hard to tell what's going on. Besides that "inside the jar file" is neither possible (ok, with some effort it is) nor sensible: you'd not want to put data that can change into your application's archive.

Comment: I really really doubt it's arbitrary. Either you specified the path somewhere, or it creates them in the *current* directory, i.e. the directory from which you executed the command. You posted no code, no configuration at all though, so it's quite hard to help.

Comment: Also, are the files all in the same 'arbitrary location' or are they all going to different places on the file system?   In addition, I second both of the above comments, some code would help greatly